# Node.Js Server keeps crashing with no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, crash, socket.io

I am currently taking care of a project for a business that is basically a real time message board used to interact with other employees.

I have taken this over after the basics had already been developed and I am quite new to Node, and developing in general.

Our server just quits unexpectedly at random times with no error. It happens up to once per day, sometimes with very little server load, sometimes with heavy server load.

There is a listener for uncaught exceptions:

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // handle the error safely
    console.log("Uncaught exception: "+err);
    });
```

and we also print errors to console and a log file, but neither ever shows an error just before it quits!

We are using express and socket.io

Any help would be appreciated.

This is basically the code we have in the server. I am logging all the different processes I can see and I am not getting any error messages at all and it always seems to crash when something different is executing:

```
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    // handle the error safely
    console.log("Uncaught exception: "+err);
    });

app.configure(function(){
        app.use(express.cookieParser());    // Allow parsing of cookies
        app.use(express.json());                            // Support JSON parsng
        app.use(express.urlencoded());                      // Support URL encoded params
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');                      // Define view engine as EJS
        app.use(express.session({store: sessionStore, secret: sessSecret, key: sessKey}));
        app.use(app.router);                                // Use routes
        app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // Define public directory
    });



    var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(app_port, function(){
        console.log("Express server listening on port " + app_port);
    });

    // Require our routes module
    var routesModule = require('./modules/routes.js')(app);
    var svc_io  = require("/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/index.js")(https);
    var dbmodule = require("./modules/db.js");


var moment = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/moment/moment.js');
    var fs = require('/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js');
    var util = require('util');

    console.log = function(d){
        var time = moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS');

        var log_file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/debug.log', {flags: 'a'});
        var log_stdout = process.stdout;

        log_file.write(time + ' : ' + util.format(d) + '\n');
        log_stdout.write(time + ' : ' + util.format(d) + '\n');
        log_file.end();
    };

    var io = svc_io.listen(server);
    var socketModule = require('./modules/socket.js')(app, io, sessionStore, cookieParser, sessKey, sessSecret);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think we can really provide you a solution with such a few code. The exception may be caused by many things, but I'm not sure we actually have any clue to say "it's a server problem" or "it's a problem related to your code", because we have no idea of how your code is actually structured (both client & server) and what server and infrastructure you actually have... Can you please give us more informations?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. There is quite a lot of code we use and some of it is business sensitive so I know it is going to be hard for me to get help.

Basically the whole application is split into the server, a login module, a routes module, a socket module and an Oracle database module. I don't know which parts of code to share. 

Everytime this happens it seems to be after some different event that we can't replicate... I know this is probably not much help!

Comment: Then I would suggest you to actually log everything that is happening and try to understand if there is any relation between the events themselves. If there is no relation between the events, then it may just be a problem related to the core of nodejs (I doubt that, though) or it may most likely be a problem related to your server or to the infrastructure itself. The best way to understand that (at least to me) is logging every single action that is happening on the server side, because it is the side which is actually creating the problems.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else reaching this question from Google: I had a crashing Node.js server with no errors at all, and was pulling my hair out for an hour before realising that it was because in my code somewhere I was writing to a file like `writeFileSync("./foo.json", "…")`, which would of course normally be fine, but this was causing the server to "crash" because I was using PM2 to "watch" the server directory for file changes - i.e. whenever a file changes in the server directory, PM2 restarts the server. I solved this by adding a `watch_ignore` config for the `.data` folder and put `foo.json` in there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to comment this and yu will get the point of error.

```
// process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
// handle the error safely
//console.log("Uncaught exception: "+err);
// });
```